# Check if first character is equal to last character in a string

Tags: python-3.x

```
def first_and_last(message):   if (message[0] == message[-1]):
    return True   elif (message[0] != message[-1]):
    return False

print(first_and_last("else")) print(first_and_last("tree"))
print(first_and_last(""))
```

Comment: I am using the above code and getting index out of range error

Comment: An empty string has neither an element ``0`` nor ``-1``, since it has neither a first or last character. What is your desired result in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide if an empty string shoudl be `True` or `False`. Assuming message will always be a string. you can first test if its a non empty string then return the boolean of first char equal to last char. otherwise In this case i have assumed return false for empty strings.

```py
def first_and_last(message):
    if message:
        return message[0] == message[-1]
    return False

print(first_and_last("else"))
print(first_and_last("tree"))
print(first_and_last("A"))
print(first_and_last(""))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
True
False
True
False
```

Comment: You could shorten this to ``return message and message[0] == message[-1]``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi that my friend is some succient python code. I never would have come up with that but its very nice